# How to processing multiple strings together if different sequentially otherwise?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, executorservice, blockingqueue

Below is a simple code only trying to use the same executorService for a type of string, which is not solving  **my problem** of *processing multiple strings together unless they are of the same type, in case they are of the same type the thread must wait for the previous string to be processed.*
Also, please suggest if I can make use of blocking queue to implement this, and how?

Another approach I could think of, but not able to implement -
Put all threads that have picked one type to wait in a queue, so they get processed sequentially. Meanwhile other types are picked up by other threads.

> **Type A** <-Thread1<-Thread2<-Thread3<-Thread8
>   **Type B** <-Thread4<-Thread5
>   **Type C** <-Thread9... and so on.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class SOS {
    volatile static int i = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        ExecutorService executorService1 = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        ExecutorService executorService2 = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        ExecutorService executorService3 = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        ExecutorService[] e = {executorService1, executorService2, executorService3};
        String[] FeedList = {"A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "A", "C", "C", "C", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A",
            "A", "C"};



        final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int k = 0;
        while (i < FeedList.length) {
            Callable<String> callable = new MyTask(FeedList, i);

            k = hash(FeedList, i, new RandomGen().Types());

            Future<String> success = e[k].submit(callable);
            if (!success.get().contains("Success"))
                System.out.println("Failure");
            i++;

        }

        e[0].shutdown();
        e[1].shutdown();
        e[2].shutdown();
        final long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Total execution time: " + (endTime - startTime));
    }

    private static int hash(String[] FeedList, int n, int numOfType) throws InterruptedException {

        HashMap<String, Integer> h = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        int k = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < FeedList.length; i++) {
            if (!h.containsKey(FeedList[i])) {
                k++;
                if (k >= numOfType)
                    k = 0;
                h.put(FeedList[i], k);

            }
            if (h.containsKey(FeedList[i]))
                Thread.sleep(1);

        }

        return h.get(FeedList[n]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to check I did get your requirement: All instances of a type need to be processed sequentially? So, there only can be as much concurrent activity as there are different types?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `get` right after submitting, which waits for the execution to finish. That means that the executors will not be executing in parallel.

You should make all the `Futures<...>`s first, and than call `get` afterwards:

```
List<Future<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();

while (i < FeedList.length) {
    Callable<String> callable = new MyTask(FeedList, i);

    k = hash(FeedList, i, new RandomGen().Types());

    Future<String> success = e[k].submit(callable);
    list.add(success);            

    i++;    
}

for(Future<String> f : list) {
    if (!f.get().contains("Success"))
        System.out.println("Failure");
}
```

---

I also don't see the point in making `i` volatile, since it only gets accessed from one thread. It gets copied, when passing it to `MyTask`'s constructor.

Comment: This code is far from the solution I am looking for, but thanks for correcting me. :)
Also, looking at the output, this fix works I am not sure.

Comment: @user3055952 I had to replace ```hash``` with another method since I don't know about ```RandomGen```. I made a method that simply returned an ```int``` based on if the string was "A", "B", or "C". I don't know how you're testing the results, but using ```System.currentTimeMillis``` is know to give inconsistent results, see: [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java). Lastly, a data set this small, might not be enough to amortize the cost of going parrallel.